# npm install ip-cidr not compatible with npm version

Tags: node.js

root:/opt/pronghorn-workspace/app-ip_address# npm install ip-cidr
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for ip-address@7.1.0: wanted: {"node":">= 10"} (current: {"node":"8.17.0","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: ip-address@7.1.0

- ip-cidr@3.0.2
  added 4 packages from 4 contributors and audited 4 packages in 0.953s
  found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Instead of just posting an error message, tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Node version.

1. Check which version you are currently using with: `node -v`
2. Next, clear npm cache with the command: `npm cache clean -f`
3. Install n globally: `npm install -g n`
4. Now that you have n installed, you can use the module to install the latest stable release of Node.js: `n stable`
   Alternatively, you can install the Node.js release with the latest features: `n latest`
   Or, install a specific version number with: `n [version.number]`